misbehavior of the 2 employees
I am currently a contract employee at a company. After demonstrating strong performance and alignment with the role over 24 months, I was recently encouraged to apply for an internal posting for a permanent position.
Follow-up on Questions #1 and #2
My boss has gone on long-term leave (with uncertainty about whether they will return). A planned three-way meeting was repeatedly canceled and ultimately removed from the schedule.
The new boss’s manager has asked me to report the incident to HR. I have prepared a detailed document spanning several pages with my documentation. However, I am wondering why the manager is not addressing the situation directly, instead of asking me to do so.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

LET IT GO!
That is the answer
Just move on.
This question will likely be closed in a few minutes anyway.
Again, LET IT GO! PLEASE!

That is right. "LET IT GO" is the best strategy in many situations in real life. Some people just don't realize that "LET IT GO" is NOT just a song from the kid's movie "FROZEN" :-)

Upvote from me, but my version is "not your monkey, not your circus".

I just want to make sure those two bad employees do not get promotions, as they were poor in their performance.

:) Buy the company and fire them. Let it go. Every second that you spend on these silly people is time that you aren't working on your career or spending with your family. Do these people really deserve this hold on your life? Do well in you advancement and that is the best revenge. Forget them better still (adaped from a Who song).
